# How to remove the balls that appear in the kivy window?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I was wondering if it is possible, I believe so, removes the balls that appear in the window of the kivy when I click on it with the right button. It seems to me that it is a pattern, and I see no use.

[image]

I think it's a simple thing to solve...
I also have another question, and not to need to post a new question, here goes.

Let's assume I made a kivy window without borders:

```
from kivy import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', '1')
```

Now my doubt. How do I move the window by dragging the mouse?

Comment: The red dots are multitouch emulation, there's a config option to disable it. And for your other question, if you have two unrelated questions you _should_ ask them separately. The answer is that you can update Window.pos, or more broadly that many window managers provide methods of moving windows around even if they don't have decorations.

Comment: Yes, but how do I disable this? I looked at the document and i couldn't find it. Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code at the top of your main `.py` file:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')
```

See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.providers.mouse.html#using-multitouch-interaction-with-the-mouse).

Answer (score -1):

Just left-click on the ball you want to remove

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32084188)